# Swagger in .net core 5 give me the error --No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

When I request any API endpoint from Swagger UI give me the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was
> specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default
> schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string
> defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action
> configureOptions).
>
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext
> context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
>
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate
> next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy,
> PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
>
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)
>
> at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
>
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> HEADERS
>
> =======
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
>
> Authorization: Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOiIzIiwiTG9naW5JZCI6ImFkbWluIiwiVXNlclR5cGVJZCI6IjEiLCJFbWFpbCI6ImEiLCJNb2JpbGUiOiJhIiwianRpIjoiMWU1MDY3ODAtMWRjNS00MDYzLWFkMTktMDdlMjg4MzAxOWVjIiwiZXhwIjoxNjIzNDYzNjQ4LCJpc3MiOiJlZHVjYXJlLmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6ImVkdWNhcmUuY29tIn0.G2-D_oIdwUDw_3iz87jxWBIMabFpLlR5ASjCr109kNM
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Host: localhost:21068
>
> Referer: http://localhost:21068/swagger/index.html

the Swagger configuration is given below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Edu Care API", Version = "v1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "Please insert the authorization token into field",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "bearer"
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                    },
                    new string[] { }
                }
                });

            });
        }


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Edu Care API v1");
                //c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });

app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();           

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

}
```

my base controller as below

```
 [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BaseController : ControllerBase
    {

    }
```

my API end point as below

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]    
    public class AcademicFeeConfigurationController : BaseController
    {

 [HttpGet]
        [Route("[action]")]
        public IActionResult GetFeeRelatedAllSli()
        {
            try
            {
                object sli = new
                {
                    FeeTypeSli = new FeeTypeService(context).FeeTypeSli(),
                    ClassInfoSli = new ClassInfoService(context).ClassInfoSli(),
                    SectionSli = new SectionInfoService(context).SectionInfoSli(),
                    AcademicSessionSli = new AcademicSessionInfoService(context).AcademicSessionSli(),
                };

                return Ok(sli);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               
                ResponseModel.Notification = UtilityHelper.CreateNotification(Helpers.ExceptionMessage(ex), Enums.NotificationType.Error);
                return StatusCode(500, ResponseModel);
            }
        }
}
```

Missing maybe something. Can anyone give any suggestion/solution

Comment: Do you have any authentication settings inside the startup.cs ConfigureServices method?  It seems you don't set any authentication sechma and use Authorize inside the api controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about Swagger your code is missing AddAuthentication(). The example below registers the Authentication schemes (JWT & Cookie) while using the JWT as the default scheme. More info in the [Docuementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options))
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => Configuration.Bind("CookieSettings", options));
```